# using arrow function on Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

having a difficult time converting a Jquery map function to an arrow function.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7v15yqj/).

```js
// find elements
$('button').click(function(e) {
  let answerArray = $(`[name="foo"]`).map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  console.log(answerArray)
  
  let answerArray2 = $(`[name="foo"]`).map(x => $(x).val()).get();
  console.log(answerArray2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="foo">
<input name="foo">
<button>
  enter
</button>
```

but I am receiving.

> VM118 jquery.js:7977 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'toLowerCase' of undefined
>       at jQuery.fn.init.val (VM102 jquery.js:7977)
>       at HTMLInputElement.$.map.x ((index):74)
>       at VM102 jquery.js:194
>       at Function.map (VM102 jquery.js:443)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.map (VM102 jquery.js:193)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. ((index):74)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM102 jquery.js:5183)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (VM102 jquery.js:4991)

Comment: `Array.from($('[name="foo"]'), x => x.value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your code *x*  refers to index *not* element thus you are getting the error.

Use correct `callback` function arguments of [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

> Type: Function( Integer **index**, Element **domElement** ) => Object
>   A function object that will be invoked for each element in the current set.

```js
// find elements
$('button').click(function(e) {

  let answerArray2 = $(`[name="foo"]`).map((i, x) => $(x).val()).get();
  console.log(answerArray2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="foo">
<input name="foo">
<button>
  enter
</button>
```